# Find data based on data-driven conditions from another table ("At least One" of and "Required")

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, data-driven

Using data in the following format as an example, in which table B stores orders, and table A stores conditions for which a promotional discount may be applied to orders in B:

```
DROP TABLE #A
DROP TABLE #B   

-- Table #A stores information about the requirements for allowing promotions
CREATE TABLE #A(
    PromoName varchar(50),
    Product varchar(250),
    ConditionType varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('PromoA','Product1','AT LEAST ONE')
INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('PromoA','Product2','AT LEAST ONE')
INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('PromoA','Product3','REQUIRED')
INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('PromoA','Product4','REQUIRED')
INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('PromoA','Product5','REQUIRED')

-- Table B contains order information, and whether products from #A are in the order
CREATE TABLE #B(
    QuoteID varchar(50),
    ProductName varchar(250)
)
INSERT INTO #B VALUES ('Quote1','Product1')
INSERT INTO #B VALUES ('Quote2','Product3')
INSERT INTO #B VALUES ('Quote3','Product4')
INSERT INTO #B VALUES ('Quote4','Product5')

-- Select * from #A
-- Select * from #B
```

I need to find data in #B that matches the requirements set in #A.  So, in the example data I provided, the records in #B should be returned because the requirements from A are met...that being that the orders in #B contain "at least one" of either "Product1" or "Product2" (because #B indeed contains Product 1) and it also contains all of the "REQUIRED" items of Product3, Product4, and Product5.

But, if one of the required fields were missing, like if we were to remove Product5 from #B, then no records should be returned from table #B.  Likewise, no records should return if table #B contained neither products 1 or 2.

How can I get this data?  I attempted something here which seems logically correct to me, but it's not and I think this may be turning more complex than I initially thought.  Here's my code:

```
;WITH CTE_Required as --These are "required" promotion requirements indicating that an item must be 
-- on the order
(
    Select PromoName,Product,ConditionType from #A 
    where ConditionType = 'REQUIRED'
),
CTE_AtLeastOne as --These are requirements that "at least one" of the "at least one" items must exist 
-- on the order
(
    Select PromoName,Product,ConditionType from #A
    where ConditionType = 'AT LEAST ONE'
),
CTE_PromoRequiredRestrictionNotMet as -- The "required" restriction test has failed for these
(
    Select a.Product
    from CTE_Required a
    left join #B b on b.ProductName = a.Product
    where b.QuoteID is null -- Data is in the "required" list but it's not in #B
),
CTE_PromoAtLeastOneRestrictionNotMet as --This data needs at least one in #B, but none exist in #B
(
    Select a.Product
    from CTE_AtLeastOne a
    left join #B b on b.ProductName = a.Product
    where b.QuoteID is not null 
),
CTE_PromoRequiredRestrictionMet as --These are items not in the failed items ("required" test passes)
(
    Select * from #B where ProductName not in 
    (
        Select * from CTE_PromoRequiredRestrictionNotMet
    ) 
),
CTE_PromoAtLeastOneRestrictionMet as -- These pass the "At least one" test 
(
    Select * from #B where ProductName not in 
    (
        Select * from CTE_PromoRequiredRestrictionNotMet
    ) 
)
Select * from CTE_PromoRequiredRestrictionMet c -- Get items that passed both tests
join CTE_PromoAtLeastOneRestrictionMet d on c.ProductName = d.ProductName
```

This returns all records correctly when the products/conditions match (in the listed data example above), however it's not correct if I remove a "required" product from #B.  So, if I remove product 3 from #B, then the results still return Products 1,2 and 4, which I do not want.  I only want to return records where *all* conditions are met.

In my code, I kind of get why it doesn't work...I have several CTEs set up to get the data in small bits (I'm trying to differentiate the data that meets the "REQUIRED" requirements and separately the data that meets the "AT LEAST ONE" requirements, then find the ones that meet both. (And there are intermediate CTEs that used left joins to find which things are in #A that are NOT in #B, which I then use with a "not in" to decide what is in #A and #B). I have a feeling I need a group-by clause somewhere.

In any case, what query could I use to select either all-or-none records from #B, based on whether all of the data-driven conditions are met defined in #A? Aside from the inner join at the end on the CTE's containing passed data items, I've tried a few different joins including union and none are totally working. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: TO be clear, there may be more data, so in table #A I have "promoA" listed, but there may also be a promoB and I don't want promoA results to affect promoB results.

Answer (score 1):

This might work best as a stored procedure, but see my logic below.

```
--DROP #C IF EXISTS
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#C') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #C

--INSERT ALL OF #B INTO WORKING TABLE #C
SELECT * INTO #C FROM #B

--IF A REQUIRED PRODUCT IS MISSING, DELETE RECORDS FROM #C
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #A A LEFT JOIN #C C ON A.PRODUCT = C.PRODUCTNAME WHERE A.CONDITIONTYPE ='REQUIRED' AND C.PRODUCTNAME IS NULL) DELETE FROM #C

--IF ANY 'AT LEAST ONE' PRODUCTS ARE MISSING, DELETE RECORDS FROM $C
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #C C WHERE C.PRODUCTNAME IN (SELECT PRODUCT FROM #A A WHERE A.CONDITIONTYPE ='AT LEAST ONE')) DELETE FROM #C

--RETURN RECORDS (IF ANY)
SELECT * FROM #C
```

- John

Comment: Thank you!! I think this works. Now, I didn't specify this...but what if my tables both have more records for different groups of Products, or different promotions?  In other words...I don't want to clear the entire table C every time there's no match...I would only want to delete the records for that particular set of product mappings/Promos (let's say a "promo B" this time, that didn't have a match?  In this case could I change the "Delete from #C" piece to "Delete from #C WHERE..." and in the where clause (or maybe by an additional join) only delete the items that need deleted?

Comment: Yes, that logic would be sound. The trick is to try and get a boolean type result for each record to determine if it stays or gets deleted. If you have more than all or nothing being returned, you may want to add an additional column to the working table (#C) called "MeetsPromotion" or something to that effect that would be able to hold the result of additional checks like what you're describing.